# Set style of dots in jqplot with help of an array

Tags: jqplot

I have a simple plot like this:

```
 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', data, {
        seriesColors: ["red", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12",
     "#953579", "#4b5de4", "#d8b83f", "#ff5800", "#0085cc"],
        seriesDefaults: {
            showLine: false,
           }
```

});

so in seriesColor I set the order in which the lines of the plot a colored. So my question is can I also set the style like this. I want to have an Array like ["diamond", "x", "square"] to set the style. The first line should habe the style "Diamond", the second the style "x" and so on...
is this possible?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining `markerOptions` to each series.

`series:[ 
          {
            // Use a diamond shaped marker.
            markerOptions: { style:'dimaond' }
          }, 
          {
            // Use a diamond shaped marker.
            markerOptions: { style:"x" }
          },
          { 
            // Use (open) circlular markers.
            markerOptions: { style:"circle" }
          }, 
          {
            // Use filled square markers.
            markerOptions: { style:"filledSquare" }
          }
      ]`

This will applied in same order, in which you have defined the `data` and `seriesColors`
Optionally, you can also define the size of the marker.

Check this example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/line-charts.html)

Hope it helps.